# messed up partitions during mint installation

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

I was using a windows10/Ubuntu 14 LTS dual-boot, when I decided to swap out Ubuntu for Mint. I downloaded the `.iso`, made a Live-USB, started Mint from the USB, pressed install and the installer told me there was Ubuntu on my system already.

I clicked to replace Ubuntu with Mint, got to the next page, was unsure whether I would keep my dual boot after the installation so I went back to the page were the installer told me that I have Ubuntu installed already.

Just that now the installer tells me, that there is no OS found on the harddrive! No actual installation of Mint happened yet, it was just setting things up.

I thought this is a bug, tried to restart, got some kind of blue screen from windows 10 (can't start from this, need to rescue), went into UEFI and put grub back to the top of the booting hierarchy.

Now grub doesn't boot neither, telling me "no partition found" and gives me the grub rescue command line, that didn't really help me.

What happened? Did I mess up at some point? can I go back to the setting I had? The only way to boot right now is from the Mint Live-USB and when opening `gparted`, I only see 3 partitions:

```
/dev/sda1 fat32 SYSTEM 512 MiB
/dev/sda2 unknown 244 MiB
/dev/sda3 lvm2 pv mint-vg 930.77 GiB
```

Whereas before that, the installation had like 10 partitions, now they all seem kind of merged into the sd3 with the weird file system.

So, please, can somebody help me out of this mess? **:(**

Comment: "Can somebody help me out of this mess?" probably not, unfortunately. Although most everyone here has done something like that at least once, but we learned from it as I hope you will too. Make backups, make certain that you are asking the software to *really* do what you think you are. If in doubt, check first, then, check again. [Always mount a scratch monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_monkey) (that story is from 1979, you are part of a long, glorious history in computerdom; presumably, you didn't kill any monkeys in the process).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, somewhere on the way, you decided to encrypt your home directory, so basically, you need to restore from your most current system back-up.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news*

Comment: how is this even possible, it wasn't even installing when I decided to abort the installation wizard.

Comment: I don't know the exact buttons you clicked during installation... And if this answer helped you, don't forget to accept.  Also: if you're not making back-ups now, start doing so, especially before doing something as dangerous as replacing an OS...  **:-(**

Answer (score 1):

You could give [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) a shot, ideally on a copy of the disk (assuming you have another computer you can copy it to...). TestDisk can recover partitions, if the disk hasn't be rewritten, and failing that [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) can be used to recover some types of data. Do read all the documentation before using either tool!

Answer (score 1):

**Do not write anything on the hard disk. and do not reformat**
With every write operation you make you're at risk of replacing existing data; making it unrecoverable.
Do your data recovery attempts (use tools like the ones Stephen Kitt suggested) and hopefully recover as much data as possible. And then start out new. 
Do not forget to file a bug report to the [ubuntu installer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-installer). (Mint uses ubuntu installer).

Best of luck.